# Any Idea why vite.js is having issues in react with esbuild

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I tried installing react app with vite and after installation when i tried using npm run dev it keeps throwing this error,

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/node_modules/@esbuild/darwin-x64/bin/esbuild
  Expected in: flat namespace

failed to load config from /Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/vite.config.js
error when starting dev server:
Error: The service was stopped
    at /Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1145:25

    at Object.responseCallbacks.<computed> (/Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:
701:9)
    at Socket.afterClose (/Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:691:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1333:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mobile_banking@0.0.0 dev: `vite`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mobile_banking@0.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

please what can i do.

I've tried deleting the package.json and package-lock.json and installing it back using npm install but it still won't work.

Comment: How did you install your npm dependecies? Did you use `npm install` or copy them from somewhere?

Comment: i used npm install

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the `node_modules` directory and run `npm i` again. Then `npm run build`.

Comment: You need to explain the logic behind the solution you propose.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, there seem 2 type of issues. The one with npm package i.e. with "@esbuild/darwin-x64", I found its equivalent in Linux is "esbuild/linux-x64". Look for the package updates, or try upgrading and downgrading the current esbuild package version, you can see it on your package.json file.

Old Version, [image: old version package]

Upgraded Version [image]

In my case upgrading from 0.15.10 to 0.17.17 worked as expected.

If you face any kind of peer issue with other packages while installing, like this:
[image]

Run the package install command with --legacy-peer-deps

```
npm i @esbuild/linux-x64 --legacy-peer-deps
```

References:
[esbuild/linux-x64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@esbuild/linux-x64)
[esbuild/darwin-x64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@esbuild/darwin-x64)

The second issue most likely with vite's configuration file missing.

- failed to load config from /Users/KELVIN/Desktop/ZZZ/react/mobile_banking/vite.config.js

Make sure you have vite.config.js file in the appropriate location.
Related issue [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/failed-to-load-config-from-viteconfigjs)